# Angularjs + Laravel: Get properties of Eloquent Relationships in nested ng-repeat

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

What I'm trying to do is to get a property of the deepest hierarchy of Eloquent Relations in a nested `ng-repeat`.

Here is the relationship.

`Order ..hasMany.. SubItems ..belongTo.. Product`

There is a model `Order`, which `hasMany` model `SubItems`. This `SubItems` model `belongsTo` a model `Product`.

I have an array of `Order`, and I'd like to access the relevant `Product` with `ng-repeat` from the each `Order` object.

```
    <table>
        <tbody ng-repeat="order in tc.orders" >//I use "as" syntax, so I use "tc."here
            <tr ng-click="tc.showOrderDetail(order.id)">
                <td ng-bind="order.id"></td>
                <!-- "order.id" works in both lines -->
            </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="subItem in order.subItems">
                    <td ng-bind="subItem.price"></td>
                    <!-- This "subItem.price" appears -->
                    <td ng-bind="subItem.product.name"></td>
                    <!-- This "subItem.product.name" doesn't appear -->
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The second level of the relationship (`SubItems`) can be accessed by putting a `.`, but apparently I need to use a different way to access the third level (`Product`).

I'd appreciate if you'd give any advice.

**Additional information**

When I use Laravel's foreach loop, this can be accessed by...

`{{$subItem->product->name}} //This works fine!`

The controller method is...

```
public function getOrders()
{
    $orders = $this->order->with('customer', 'subitems')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return $orders;
}
```

Comment: Please include your controller code.  The `product` must not be loading on your `subItem` model, so we need to see your controller in order to help

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I added it. Believe it or not, there was no error when I was using Laravel's forloop and `product` was related to `subitem`.

Comment: When you call `$subItem->product` it automatically loads it for you.  You have to manually load it if you want it to appear in the JSON form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're not telling Laravel to eagerLoad the Project Model onto your Subitem Model. you need to add the Product eager loading like so :

```
$this->order->with('customer', 'subitems.product')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

and access it like any other javascript object `subItem.product.name`

The reason it worked for you in Laravel foreach loop was because when you request a relationship like an attribute in Laravel i.e `$subItem->product` and not as a method, Laravel automatically instantiate the relationship Eloquent object, into the Model object.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd like to ask one more question... After reading the documentation, I don't think it is a common practice to put a dot (`.`) between models in Laravel. Is it common to do this when indicating the Eloquent relationships in controllers? Or, how did you find it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

scroll down to Nested Eager Loading